How to set prefix of application name into output information about system metric name when using OpenTelemetry?
When I use OpenTelemetry.Metrics library for use metrics of "System.Net.Http" namespace or other systems metrics, then I get metric and labels in format.
How to set default context name for metric and labels like this (prefix - "application")?
enter image description here. Also I need to add some tags globally (env, app, version). Try to use Attributes but it not help (updated):
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 builder.Services.AddConnections();
 builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
 builder.Services
     .AddOpenTelemetry()
     .WithMetrics(x =>
     {
         x.ConfigureResource(t => t.AddService(
             serviceName: "test",//builder.Configuration.GetValue("AppName", defaultValue: "test-metrics")!,
             serviceVersion: "v1", //typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Version?.ToString() ?? "unknown",
             serviceInstanceId: Environment.MachineName));
         x.AddHealthChecksInstrumentation(a => a.IncludeHealthCheckMetadata = true);
         x.AddPrometheusExporter();
         x.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
         x.AddBuiltInMeters();
     });

 var app = builder.Build();

 app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();
 app.MapPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();

 app.Run();

enter image description here

Typically, it is not what you should do. Metric names should be the same across whole infrastructure (if you are using OpenTelemetry, even it should be standardized for whole industry).
Please consider using Resources. You can use the one called service.name or create something custom. Your backend should allow to filter by this.

Hello. I updated the code example. I also need to add some tags  globally into label information (app, env). But it not works for me.

Prometheus will accept metrics from different microservices, that why I need tags in label.

This x.SetResourceBuilder(..) resets what you have done in .ConfigureResource(t => t.AddService(...).
Consider replacing SetResourceBuilder by ConfigureResource

It does not help (updated). I think it's all about PrometheusExporter.

Consider https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol. It should be supported by any new Prometheus https://prometheus.io/blog/2024/03/14/commitment-to-opentelemetry/

It only has 1 class OpenTelemetryProtocolExporterEventSource, can anything be useful from it?

I am suggesting using OTLP as an exporter. This protocol is native to the data structure operatimg across OTLP. There will be less conversions. See  https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/core-1.9.0/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol/OtlpMetricExporterExtensions.cs#L25
